# Utilizing (or faking) AO in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, ambient-occlusion

I've ported over a game character to Blender and I'm interested in rendering an animation with Cycles. However, I've read (and found while using) Blender that it doesn't seem to utilize AO while using Cycles since it's using a more realistic form of light?

Basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to still use the AO map in this render mode. And if not, is there any way I can compensate for it? The AO map essentially just adds shadowed crevices to a face, like around the inner corners of the eyes.

I saw some threads on others with similar issues but they're for older forms of Blender and I can't seem to figure out how to follow them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably just get away with multiplying your AO map with your Basecolor (or basecolor image texture) before connecting it to the Basecolor socket (assuming you're using a Principled BSDF - use "color" for any other shader)

[image: AO]